# Sepearte two overlaped line in proc sgplot

Tags: sas, sgplot

I have the following graph showing two variables x and y for each group on y-axix. I'd like to separate blue and red line for each group for a clearer presentation; something like having two very close line (one for x and one for y) for each group on the y-axis. Any suggestion? [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAS 9.4, you can use JITTER option in your SCATTER statement to separate the lines.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/grstatproc/p1lcbd3lhs3t3bn1jk6d8sjt2yqx.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that JITTER works only with scatter statement. I have created the dot plot using the following code and it appears that JITTER is invalid there. `proc sgplot data=have ;
dot change_cat / response=x1  stat=mean limitstat=clm   ;
dot change_cat / response=x2  stat=mean limitstat=clm  ;
run;
`